# If a start-up script in `init.d` has standard output, where is that logged if anywhere?

Tags: rhel, logs, init-script

We have a startup script that is symbolicly linked to `/etc/rc0.d/K01ourapp`. Apparently, it is not working as expected during shutdown.

The script actually does a few `echo` calls that may help in troubleshooting. Where does that output get logged (if anywhere)?

I am using RHEL5.

Comment: Does this help? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42833/how-to-write-init-d-script-log-messages-to-disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings sent to the standard output go to `/dev/console` (most often you can see them on your screen, but not always). To log these messages, you can use bootlogd, which, as described in its man page, "runs in the background and copies all strings sent to the `/dev/console` device to a logfile", and the default logfile is `/var/log/boot`.